# How to watch and retrieve param's id query data with vue 3 composition api without refrshing the page manualy

Tags: vuejs3

I have 2 buttons one for drinks and one for food

both buttons are on the same url route

However when I click on any of them I get an id sent with params to the same url but with the id change there is a string change so i do a for loop and I get this new data back again ,however they don't show up by them self because the need either a watcher that watches the params query or they need manual refresh , how can I APPLY A WATCHER FOR THIS

I checked your course and didn't see how can I get data brought from the backend when I

##### template

passing item route id

```html
<div v-if="documents">

<div v-for=" doc in formattedDocuments" :key="doc.id">

<router-link class="links" :to="{name:'B2DetailsEN', params: {id:doc.id} } ">

looping through an array in the id

<div v-for="item in cate.items" :key="item.id">

<h1>{{item.title}}

{{item.price}}

</h1>

</div>

</div>
```

get document composable that brings all data from firebase

#### setup

```js
const { error4, document:cate } = getDocument('menuB2En', route.params.id)
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT, it's rude. Also please learn how to [edit] your questions and [how to format text](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Thank you daniel for editing my question , I think its hard to get an answer on that , its just because vue 3 is weird and has different ways of working like option api or composition api .......... maybeI  should quit and go back to react

Comment: I would advice to use opion api, in you can `created()` and `updated()` respectively composition api is a bit weird. If I understood well your question the params in route changes but page doesnot re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not understand your use case completely.
If you stay on the same page/route/Component, you could use `ref`- or `reactive`-objects and simple Buttons calling functions in your setup instead of Router-Links to update values.
See: https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref

But if you still want to retrieve the route params or the query params in Vue 3 composition API, you need to use Vue Router's `useRoute()`. With this object, you can do as you did with good ol' `$route` from Vue 2. There is also a `useRouter()` to get the router object if you need to push some routes.

For example, if your route looks something like this `your-domain.com/route?name=Zerio`:

```
import { ref } from '@vue/reactivity'
import { onBeforeMount } from '@vue/runtime-core';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
export default {
    setup() {
        const name = ref("");
        
        onBeforeMount(() => {
            const route = useRoute();
            const queryParam = route.query.name;
            if (queryParam !== undefined) {
                name.value = queryParam;
            }
        });
        
        return {
            name
        }
    },
}
```

Doing that, you can use `name` everywhere in your template and in your setup-function.

Also had to look for it a long time now, and found this article while searching, so I thought for all those who are still searching and finding this article, this could be a possible answer you are looking for.

See also: https://www.koderhq.com/tutorial/vue/composition-api-router-routing/

Answer (score 0):

See this document: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api

And in the document's example, you can watch the `route.params.id`:

```js
<script setup>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'

const route = useRoute()
const userData = ref()

// fetch the user information when params change
watch(
  () => route.params.id,
  async newId => {
    userData.value = await fetchUser(newId)
  }
)
</script>
```